# How to find out where in try-block the exception occured

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a try-catch block. In the catch block, I want to logg information where in the try block the exception occured (i.e linke numnber). thanks

Comment: What kind of "information"? No matter what the answer, you aren't really going to be able to get anything useful. If you feel you need to distinguish then you need more than one `catch` (and possibly more than one `try`).

Comment: You can read the stacktrace.

Comment: if you put break point at catch block you can see the stacktrace. it will show you the line number and the message will show you the exception message.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply try-catch block to the code where you are not sure that it will work or not     (i.e., You are doubted about the code )

When a try-catch block is applied on multiple lines, and want to know that on what line the exception has occurred, I think you need to surround each line by try-catch block.

Otherwise Exception message will reveal the error occurred during execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and look at the stack object to see where it got.  It generally gives you a line number (with lots of other "bits")

I use it to generically, get the calling method for generic error handling:

```
void DoThings(stacktrace se)
{
se.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name 
}
```

gets me the calling method info.

Comment: As per @andgeek, it is stacktrace you need.  StackTrace()